# How to set xna's TextureFilter to Point

Tags: xna-4.0

I have a little Texture2D:

myTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 512, 512, false, SurfaceFormat.Vector4);

when I try to draw it:

```
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, 512, 512), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
```

I get an exception:

"XNA Framework HiDef profile requires TextureFilter to be Point when using texture format Vector4."

How can I set TextureFilter to Point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `SamplerState.PointClamp` or `SamplerState.PointWrap` to `SpriteBatch.Begin`.